# Questionable SQL Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am going through a pluralsight course that is currently going through building an MVC application using an entity framework code-first approach. I was confused about the Database schema used for the project.

[image: Odd relationship between Securities table and it's relating tables.]

As you can see, the relationship between Securities and it's relating tables seems to be one-to-one, but the confusion comes when I realize there is no foreign key to relate the two sub-tables and they they appear to share the same primary key column.

The video before made the Securities model class abstract in order for the "Stock" and "MutualFund" model classes to inherit from it and contain all relating data. To me however, it seems that same thing could be done using a couple of foreign keys.

I guess my question is does this method of linking tables serve any useful purpose in SQL or EF? It seems to me in order to create a new record for one table, all tables would need a new record which is where I really get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ORM and EF terminology, this setup is referred to as the ["Table per Type"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) inheritance paradigm, where there is a table per subclass, a base class table, and the primary key is shared between the subclasses and the base class.

e.g. In this case, `Securities_Stock` and `Securities_MutualFund` are two subclasses of the `Securities` base class / table (possibly abstract).

The relationship will be `0..1 (subclass) to 1 (base class)` - i.e. only one of the records in `Securities_MutualFund` or `Securities_Stock` will exist for each base table `Securities` row.

There's also often a discriminator column on the base table to indicate which subclass table to `join` to, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

It is also common to enforce referential integrity between the subclasses to the base table with a foreign key.

To answer your question, the reason why there's no FK between the two subclass `instance` tables is because each `instance` (with a unique Id) will only ever be in ONE of the sub class tables - it is NOT possible for the same `Security` to be both a mutual fund and a share.

You are right, in order for a new concrete `Security` record to be added, a row is needed in both the base `Securities` Table (must be inserted first, as their are FK's from the subclass tables to the base table), and then a row is inserted into one of the subclass tables, with the rest of the 'specific' data.

If a Foreign Key was added between `Stock` and `Mutual Fund`, it would be impossible to insert new rows into the tables.

The full pattern often looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BaseTable
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY, -- Can also be Identity
    ... Common columns here

   Discriminator, -- Type usually has a small range, so `INT` or `CHAR` are common
);

CREATE TABLE SubClassTable
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY, -- Not identity, must be manually inserted
    -- Specialized SubClass columns here
    FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES BaseTable(Id)
);
```